# How can I display a popup when I click on a button using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I display a pop-up container when I click on a button using react. I am creating a find me page and I'd like to display a popup specific to the options I select using react

```
import React from 'react';

import { SubHeading } from '../../components'
import { images } from '../../constants'
import './FindUs.css'
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'lagos', label: 'Lagos' },
  { value: 'kwara', label: 'Kwara' },
  { value: 'abuja', label: 'Abuja' },
  { value: 'imo', label: 'Imo' },
  { value: 'kano', label: 'Kano' },
]

const FindUs = () => (
  <div className="app__findus flex__center section__padding">
    <div className="app__findus-text">
      <h1 className="headtext__cormorant">
        Enjoy tasty meal wherever you are...
      </h1>
      <SubHeading title="Find us" />

      <div className="app__findus-dropdown">
        <Select
          options={options} 
          placeholder="Select state"
        />

        <button className="custom__button">
          View Outlets
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="app__findus-img">
      <img src={images.side} alt="side" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default FindUs;
```

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed`?

Comment: What have you tried? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese nothing to be honest, I don't know what to do, I know I'm to create another container and then set display it to none  but getting the specific content to a select option

Comment: Step 1 then is to probably create some React state that holds a boolean value whether or not to display a popup and create the handlers to toggle it, and then step 2 is to conditionally render that popup element/component, then finally step 3 is to apply CSS to position it where you want.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't really understand what you said, I'm a noob react developer. Let me out what I'm trying to do this way. I have a drop down menu with 4 different cities, when a user selects a city and then presses the "View Outlets" button, it should popup a content specific to that city and when I change the city it should show for the chosen city

Comment: Check the Material-ui [Popover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) demos for examples of this pattern.

Comment: What is the specific content you want to display? Can you be more specific how you want to display it? Showing us in code what you are trying to do is what we're asking for, to see why something might not be working as expected for you. If you are able to include the relevant code in your question *and* create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces any issues we can help.

Comment: @DrewReese is there a way I can show you probably with an image somewhere else :( You'd understand what I want to do better if i can show you

Comment: @DrewReese this https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-microservice-3m0ztw?file=/src/App.js is my codebox, what I am trying to do is to click on the "View Outlets" and it should display different contents for the different cities

Comment: Yes, that's the understood part. The part you should try to provide to us is the part that *actually* does something. I.e. the button's `onClick` handler logic and what you want to happen when it's clicked. Is it supposed to make a network request for data related to the selected value? Is there a local JSON file with this data? Once there is data, how should it be displayed? We can't help diagnose/debug/fix code that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DrewReese, this actually made me realize something, I think I got it now. Thank you very much sir. Really appreciate :)))